# Network namespace set-up; Different results between script and manual

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04, bash, scripts

I am having trouble getting an old script working again in 16.04 after a dist-upgrade, previous installation was 14.04.  This script sets up a network namespace to isolate programs from the main network interface.

Quick outline of what is supposed to happen:

- Create network namespace, named as `ns1`.
- Create pair of veth interfaces, named as `veth1` and `vpeer1`
- Move interface `vpeer1` to the network namespace `ns1`
- Assign IP address to interface `veth1` and bring it UP
- Assign IP address to interface `vpeer1`, bring it UP.
- Bring up interface `lo` on network namespace `ns1`
- Create a default route between the veth pairs.
- Change `ip_forwarding` to 1
- Change iptables `FORWARD` to `DROP` and flush, flush iptables nat.
- Create entry for postrouting (MASQUERADE) and two FORWARD entries are created, this allows forwarding of traffic between outside and inside the network namespace.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

NS="ns1"
VETH="veth1"
VPEER="vpeer1"
VETH_ADDR="10.200.1.1"
VPEER_ADDR="10.200.1.2"

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
echo "You must be root to run this script"
exit 1
fi

# Remove namespace if it exists.
ip netns del $NS &>/dev/null

# Create namespace
ip netns add $NS

# Create veth link.
ip link add ${VETH} type veth peer name ${VPEER}

# Add peer-1 to NS.
ip link set ${VPEER} netns $NS

# Setup IP address of ${VETH}.
ip addr add ${VETH_ADDR}/24 dev ${VETH}
ip link set ${VETH} up

# Setup IP ${VPEER}.
ip netns exec $NS ip addr add ${VPEER_ADDR}/24 dev ${VPEER}
ip netns exec $NS ip link set ${VPEER} up
ip netns exec $NS ip link set lo up
ip netns exec $NS ip route add default via ${VETH_ADDR}

# Enable IP-forwarding.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Flush forward rules.
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD

# Flush nat rules.
iptables -t nat -F

# Enable masquerading of 10.200.1.0.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ${VPEER_ADDR} -o p119p1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i p119p1 -o ${VETH} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o p119p1 -i ${VETH} -j ACCEPT
```

p119p1 is my ethernet adapter, change to whatever yours is for testing.

To test this connection, when operational, `ip netns exec ns1 ping 8.8.8.8` if it pings out, it works.

When run as a script with `yourscript.sh` as root, this doesn't work on 16.04. In 14.04 this did work.
When typed in manually, line for line as root (replacing ${variables} where needed) this does work on 16.04.

I am sure I didn't stumble on a major system flaw and I'm doing something wrong compared to the old distro.
My error when run as script, basically it complains "Destination Host Unreachable" for some reason it skips assigning an IP to veth1 when run as a script. Reason unknown to myself.

When working programs can be started inside of the namespace. Using `ip netns exec ns1 <command>`. Allowing one to separate individual programs onto their own VPN network if also using a VPN inside of the namespace.